# how to createMessageCollector() on a dm channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

hey guys anybody know how to set up

```
message.channel.createMessageCollector
```

for a dm? tried

```
message.author.dmChannel.createMessageCollector
```

with no luck.

Comment: What version of discord.js are you on? Do you have the right intents if it's v13?

Comment: v13 what intents should I have for this?

Comment: `DIRECT_MESSAGES`, and you might need the `CHANNEL` partial

Comment: alright i added the intents now how do i createMessageCollector() in the dm? @MrMythical

Answer (score 0):

All `TextBasedChannel`s have the method called `createMessageCollector` so there's no difference between `TextChannel` and `DMChannel`.
You just need to call [the method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=createMessageCollector) and pass options inside.

```js
// Filter for the collector
const filter = m => m.content.includes('discord');

// Create the collector
const collector = channel.createMessageCollector({ filter, time: 15_000 });

// Listen for new messages and when collector ends
collector.on('collect', m => console.log(`Collected ${m.content}`));
collector.on('end', collected => console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`));
```